# SSIS - Sorted Aggregating

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have source data at the day granularity and I need to aggregate it to week granularity. Most fields are easy sum aggregations. But, I have one field that I need to take Sunday's value (kinda like a "first" aggregation) and another field that I need to take Saturday's value.

The road I'm going down using SSIS is to Multicast my source data three times, doing a regular Aggregate for the easy fields, and then using lookup joins to a calendar table to match the other two to Saturday and Sunday respectively to grab those values.... then merge joining everything back together.

Is there a better way to do this?

example source data:

[image]

What the output should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a better way to do this? Yes. Don't use a complicated SSIS solution for something that is a simple SQL statement

```
SELECT 
Day, 
SUM(Sales) Sales, 
MAX(
  CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,Day) = 1 THEN BOP ELSE NULL END
) As BOP,
MAX(
  CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,Day) = 7 THEN EOP ELSE NULL END
) As EOP
FROM Table
GROUP BY Table
```

You might need to tweak the 1 and 7 depending on your server settings but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. This simply makes a lot of sense and helped me not over think it. My source data is coming from text files, would you recommend just importing the text files to staging tables and then doing all my transforms into real tables via SQL?

Comment: That is how I always do it. Some people prefer doing inline in the ETL but you can see how complicated it is. Also, using a staging table allows you to focus on the import part and separate it from the transformation part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use First_value and Last_Value for this as below:

```
select top 1 with ties datepart(week, [day]) as [Week], 
    sum(sales) over(partition by datepart(week, [day])) as Sales, 
    FIRST_VALUE(BOP) over(partition by datepart(week, [day]) order by [day]) as BOP
  , EOP = LAST_VALUE(EOP) over(partition by datepart(week, [day]) order by [day] RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) 
from #youraggregate
    Order by Row_number() over(partition by datepart(week, [day]) order by [day])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Derived column transformation to get the week first

```
DATEPART("wk", Day)
```

After that use Aggregate using Week Column